# Same endpoint, with and without @RequestParam

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In Spring Boot is it possible to have the same endpoint with and without `@RequestParam`

**A** would look like this:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/billing-codes")
public ResponseEntity getBillingCodes(
        @AuthenticationPrincipal User loggedInUser,
        @RequestParam(name = "billingCodeId") String billingCodeId,
        @RequestParam(name = "direction") String direction,
        @RequestParam(name = "limit") String limit) {
```

**B** would look like this:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/billing-codes")
public ResponseEntity getBillingCodes(
        @AuthenticationPrincipal User loggedInUser) {
```

The requests would look different

**A** request

```
/billing-codes?billingCodeId=&direction=&limit
```

**B** request

```
/billing-codes
```

It is possible to test if the `name`s of the request parameters are part of the request? Just testing if the request parameters are `null` or empty won't work since I will have case where they are and should still be processed in **A**.

Comment: May be you can try having different HttpMethods one for GET and one for POST but still its upto your design.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can only have one method by couple of `URL` and `HTTP Method` in the same `Controller`. You'll probably need to use one method with `required = false` :

```
public ResponseEntity getBillingCodes(
        @AuthenticationPrincipal User loggedInUser,
        @RequestParam(name = "billingCodeId", required = false) String billingCodeId,
        @RequestParam(name = "direction"m required = false) String direction,
        @RequestParam(name = "limit", required = false) String limit) {}
```